# Opção de classificar as perguntas pelo número de visitas

Tags: debate, suporte, novo-recurso

Atualmente na página de [perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions) do SOpt estão disponíveis seis formas de ordenação de perguntas que são:

1. <kbd>recentes</kbd>
2. <kbd>destaque</kbd>
3. <kbd>frequentes</kbd>
4. <kbd>votos</kbd>
5. <kbd>ativas</kbd>
6. <kbd>sem resposta</kbd>

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de classificar as perguntas usando como critério o *número de visitas* colocando no topo as mais visitadas? Caso não existir tal forma, seria bom saber o que a comunidade pensa a respeito de um novo recurso que permitiria classificar as perguntas pelo numero de visitas?

Segue esta imagem para ilustrar e facilitar a compreensão:

[image: imagem de sugestão]

Comment: A mais próxima que existe isso é montar um busca pelo número de visualizações, basta digitar na caixa de busca `views:10000`

Comment: No SOen estão testando um recurso de "abas" que você pode customizar como as perguntas são exibidas. Não entendi muito como funciona pois mal uso a comunidade em inglês (ps: pra participar e usar essa ferramenta beta é preciso modificar as configurações de perfil/conta). Tem que ver com o Gabe se esse recurso poderá vir pra nossa comunidade também :)

Comment: @renan eu ñ sabia disso :D

Comment: @rray neste caso este e o numero máximo de visualizações?

Comment: É o maior igual.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho por acaso já tinha pensado nisso também. Era interessante, mas não sei se se justifica.